# How can I split the windows taskbar into two parts?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

So I got one of those new ultra-wide monitors with a 5120x1440 resolution, basically two 2560x1440 screen molded together.

Now when I play games, I tend to play them on 2560x1440 for performance and visibility reasons, but having that window in the middle.
Therefore I got 1280x1440 on the left and right side for other programs like chat, browser, notepad etc.

The problem is, to run games like this it requires them to run in borderless window mode, which puts them behind the taskbar, when the taskbar is at the bottom.
I tried vertical taskbar at either right or left side, but it feels weird and makes the two lateral windows not equal size.

I'm looking for a solution now and thought of two myself.

1. Make the middle part of the taskbar (it's empty there anyway, because it is so wide) transparent **and** be able to click through it
2. Split the taskbar into two separate pieces, each 1280x32/64 (whatever height taskbar has) and have start/search/app icons on the left side and date and tray icons on the right side.

Any other ideas? Or anyone knows how do this with an existing tool or how to approach that with code via some kind of Windows API?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to hide the taskbar automatically?

1. Right-click on the taskbar and click `Taskbar settings`
2. Enable `Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode`

If it does not work as expected, how about switching monitor primary to secondary?

1. Right-click on Desktopand click `Display settings`
2. Rearrange your display

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried auto hiding the taskbar, but it still pops up when reaching the edges of the gaming window, which happens quite often for scrolling through the map (strategy game).

Unfortunately there is no second monitor. That is the benefit and the drawback of having an ultrawide screen. No bezel in the middle, but also only one physical display in the windows settings.

Unfortunately neither of your suggestions solves my problem, sorry